# DocuSign - Not able to assign locked checkboxes

Tags: docusignapi

I have three signers. I send customTabs via NodeJs call and `makeRecipientViewRequest` but I don't want one of the checkBoxes to be editable and so I add `"locked":true` but API complains: `TABGROUP_INVALID_LOCKED_TABS, Cannot include locked tabs in TabGroup children.`.

If I make the checkBox ReadOnly on the Web UI, same error. How do I make set the value of the check box and make it readonly for all signers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your locked checkbox have a "TabGroup" value defined?

Comment: No. I use it as following:
'''
```docusign.Checkbox.constructFromObject({
      tabLabel: 'isRent',
      selected: 'true',
      // "locked": "true"
     })```
'''

Comment: I feel like this is an issue with DocuSign API. When "locked:true", it shouldn't throw the error. 
Or it shouldn't throw an error when Read Only is selected on the Template Editor. That works well for Text Fields but not for Check boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read-only checkboxes cannot be part of a group. This can happen when you use the template editor and group them while editing the checkboxes. Make sure they are in different groups and then they can be read-only.

Comment: I need couple of check boxes on the document and they should be read only. The values will sent by NodeJS API call and should not be able to changed by any of the signers. How do I go about this?

Comment: I can't accept this as an answer since it doesn't answer my initial question. I don't even use TabGroups. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: would you mind having a looking at the comment above please.

Comment: ```checkBoxes.push(
     docusign.Checkbox.constructFromObject({
      tabLabel: isRent,
      selected: 'true',
      // "locked": "true"
     })
    );```
<br /><br />
```let tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
  textTabs: textFields,
  checkboxTabs: checkBoxes
 });```
<br /><br />
```docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
    email: app.coApplicant.email,
    clientUserId: app.coApplicant.email,
    name: app.coApplicant.firstName,
    roleName: 'coCustomer',
    tabs: tabs
   })```
And the rest is usual and works. Code markup doesn't seem to work. Sorry.

Comment: you only have 1 checkbox?

Comment: Around 10 checkboxes but they use same syntax

Comment: So my question is why am I not able to set `locked: true` ?

Comment: can you, for testing purposes only, try with a single checkbox? just to isolate the issue?

Comment: okay, so the issue was that I had a grouped checkbox in the template editor. Once I deleted the grouped checkboxes and added invidual ones, I was able to pass in locked:true. Thanks for your help. Please change the answer and I will accept.

Comment: I changed my answer to be more specific. Glad it's working now.

Comment: Thanks. Also please note that the acceleration profile used in the template editor is unusable. Please adjust acceleration to a lower rate. I don't think the dev ever tried moving fields with keyboard arrows. lol Thanks.